# How to allow only the server to access the DNS service

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, samba, firewall

I have a server with IP 10.0.0.1/24 and I have a firewall which is the default gateway with IP 10.0.0.2/24. I need to set permissions on the firewall to allow only the server to access the dns service. I have to use iptables.

Answer (score 2):

If your firewall FORWARD chain is doing DROP by default, this should be enough:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

(DNS uses both port 53 UDP and TCP)

If you also want to specify a DNS server 10.1.1.1 for instance:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.1 -d 10.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.1 -d 10.1.1.1 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

You may also configure the DNS server to only accept requests from the IP addresses/network which it is required to give answers in it's configuration files.

Comment: @MarvicGrima default policy on iptables is ACCEPT. You should also add these rules to bottom to drop rest.
iptables -A FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -j DROP ;
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 53 -j DROP

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming bind DNS is being used) - Why not just have the DNS service/daemon only listen on 127.0.0.1. Just add this to the options for the bind daemon:

```
listen-on { 127.0.0.1; };
```

Then have the server use the DNS server at 127.0.0.1. No firewall rules needed! :)